# Dynamically how to make checkbox check/uncheck in angularjs controller using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am new to Angular JS. When the user check/uncheck on a check box, I am calling a function in a controller using ng-click. I am passing $event to the function in controller. Using the $event, I am able to get the srcElement inside the controller function. Now I would like to set the previous check/uncheck value to the check box based on certain conditions.

```
$scope.isAccessChanged = function(event){
        if (some condition) {
            var elem = angular.element(event.srcElement);  
            /** here how to set the elem value back to whatever it was before.*/
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have check box like

```
<input ng-model="form.isSelected" type="checkbox">
```

All you need to do is:

```
$scope.form.isSelected = !$scope.form.isSelected;
```

Answer (score -1):

Avoid DOM manipulation and limit jQuery use as much as possible in angular.

I recommend using jQuery only in directives to make it less of an available option.

Try this out:

---

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foShizzle" ng-click="isAccessChanged()"/>
```

---

```
$scope.isAccessChanged = function(event){
    if(some condition){
        $scope.foShizzle = !$scope.foShizzle; // This will reverse the user's decision
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Its working fine but not when there is more than one check box as shown below.[code] <input type="checkbox" ng-model="modifyuser.searchFor" ng-click="isAccessChanged($event);">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="modifyuser.makeCorrections" ng-click="isAccessChanged($event);"> [code] How to pass the ng-model name to the function isAccessChanged ?

Comment: All I am trying to do in anjularjs is as below [code]<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function setValue(id){
 if(document.getElementById(id).checked == true){
  document.getElementById(id).checked = false;
 }else{
  document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm">
     Hello !!!<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" checked onclick="setValue(this.id)"/> <br>
     Second Time Hello !!!<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck2" onclick="setValue(this.id)"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>[code]

Comment: Remove all of that "getElementById" stuff. Don't use that in angular. Changing the value of the property will have the desired effect.
Try including the name of the model property as a string instead of $event (you don't need $event here).
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="modifyuser.searchFor" ng-click="isAccessChanged('modifyuser.searchFor');">

Then in your controller:
$scope.isAccessChanged = function(checkboxModelName){
    if(some condition){
        $scope[checkboxModelName]= !$scope[checkboxModelName];
    }
}